# Passing anonymous model to MVC Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, grid

I'm using grid MVC to generate a table which auto generates columns from a model. There will be several models to display different sets of data, however i want to keep the page used the same, e.g. /AMUK/Global?Table=Actions or /AMUK/Global?Table=Hours.

In my razor page i have defined the grid

```
@Html.Grid(Model.cockpitData).AutoGenerateColumns().Named("projectGrid").WithMultipleFilters()
```

I want to be able to pass in different models to the grid, depending on which "report" has been chosen. So instead of cockpit data it might be actionData. Can i do this with an anonymous type? Or does it have to be statically typed?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of property using reflection and pass it in Grid method.

```
public static object GetValueOfProperty(object sourceObject, string propertyName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(sourceObject, null);
}
```

and use it like.

```
@Html.Grid(GetValueOfProperty(Model, Table)).AutoGenerateColumns().Named("projectGrid").WithMultipleFilters()
```

Assuming Table will hold the value of table query string.